# Replace â€™ in perl

Tags: perl

I'm fairly new to Perl and I need to replace characters like `â€™` with `'` (i imagine there are more)

I am NOT using `UTF-8` as my `page rendering content type` but `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`

I understand I have no code samples to show but how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you saying that people are entering non-ISO 8859-1 characters into your HTML form and you need your Perl backend to convert `â€™` to `'` in the request parameters that it receives?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot updated question

Comment: Your update doesn't answer my question...

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I dont know if the characters are deemed non-ISO 8859-1 characters but they are submitting characters like I explained and I need to convert them. I imagine theres an array of these type of characters

Comment: Why are you using a legacy encoding like ISO-8859-1? UTF-8 has been well supported since around the turn of the century.

Comment: Convert them *where*? A CGI script?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot In my perl code

Comment: Why don't you just change the encoding to UTF-8 in your browser?

Comment: iirc, browsers do not necessarily obey the charset/encoding requested in a `meta` tag, at least server-generated http headers have precedence here. Also note that rendering a web page in a given charset does not prevent users from entering data in a different encoding in form fields and submitting them to the server. However, most important, what prevents you from consistently working with utf-8 in the first place?

Comment: Please provide a minimal runnable demonstration of the problem.

Comment: Note that `â€™` is the *Windows-1252* decoding of the *UTF-8* encoding of Unicode character `U+2019`. Windows-1252 is similar to ISO-8859-1 but sixteen of the code points are different. You probably want `charset="windows-1252"` in your `<meta>` element

Answer (score 2):

`â€™` is `0xE2 0x80 0x99` in the [cp1252 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), and `0xE2 0x80 0x99` is the UTF-8 encoding of the `U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` character.

The right single quotation mark is not a valid character in character set iso-8859-1, so somehow you will have to prevent this character from getting sent to the page output. Here are two ways:

1. Convert it to a printable character (like `0x27`, the apostrophe)

   ```
   $output =~ s/\x{2019}/'/g;
   print $output;
   ```
2. Rewrite it as an [HTML entity](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Common_HTML_entities_used_for_typography), which should work no matter what the page encoding is

   ```
   $output =~ s/\x{2019}/&rsquo;/g;
   print $output;
   ```

Quite possibly `\x{2019}` is not the only unprintable character in your raw output that you need to be concerned about (and even printable characters like `<` and `&` need to be encoded), and so [a module](https://metacpan.org/search?q=HTML+entities&search_type=modules) that has already solved this problem is called for. At this time I can not be sure that any particular module will solve your problem, so I will refrain from recommending one.

Comment: [Encoding::FixLatin](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encoding::FixLatin) could be used to take mixed latin1/cp1252/utf8 data and convert it to utf8 in Perl.  I'd recommend simply changing the output encoding to utf8, but if that's not an option then regexes like @mob's above could be used to restrict the output to latin1 or even ASCII.

Comment: @mob, If he's starting with text and if he's generating HTML, then he should be using `encode_entities`, not `s/\x{2019}/'/g`.